# Where should I put the Options button?

Tags: gui-design, user-expectation, menu

I've noticed that almost every Windows application has it's Options dialog accessed from a different menu and item name.

Here is an example of some of the programs on my computer, showing where the Options menu item is, and what it's called:
[image: Images of where the options can be found.]

As you can see from the pie charts, there doesn't seem to be a clear pick for the menu name, although the menu item is most often called "Preferences". This is incredibly frustrating for the user when they're searching for the link, and something that has particularly annoyed me. (This image took far too long to make!)

So, where should I put the link to the options dialog?

Comment: They're not as prescriptive on positioning as they used to be, but the current Windows guidelines do say to [use Options rather than Settings or Preferences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742392(v=vs.85).aspx#guidelines) as the menu item label.